# VLC black screen, and Disable HW Overlays

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, video, hardware-acceleration

I have a Samsung Galaxy Xcover 2, with rooted Android 4.1.2.

I have installed VLC v3.0.13 on it - which is seemingly the last version that can be installed on Android 4.1.2 (all later builds of VLC for Android require Android 4.2+). I really like VLC because it has NFS sharing built in, so I could in principle watch videos from an NFS network share, which I've done previously on other devices with great success.

The problem is: when I play any video on it (mostly 360p .mp4 obtained from `youtube-dl`), audio can be heard, however in full screen mode, screen is black; when GUI with player controls are shown, one can somewhat discern a part of the video being shown in a stripe underneath the controls; and when the device/screen is rotated, there is a brief flash of the video shown, but then it disappears, and the screen goes back to black.

I have found this thread:

- https://emby.media/community/index.php?/topic/31940-black-screen-on-video-playback/ (refers to https://forum.fairphone.com/t/vlc-player-only-shows-black-screen-for-video-playback-on-fp1/19060/7 )

... which seems to describe the exact same problem:

> The problem: No video, just a black screen except when you change
> device orientation (landscape to portrait for example), when you exit
> the playback or when you click settings button, the video appears for
> a fragment of a second.
>
> Audio and subtitles playing correctly.
>
> Probably this problem only occurs in some devices.with pre kitkat
> versions.
>
> The solution: disable HW overlays in Settings > Developer options (if
> Developer options don't shows:
> http://www.androidcentral.com/how-enable-developer-settings-android-42)

Ok, so I went to Android Settings / Developer Options, and checked "Disable HW overlays", however, that seems to have no effect (video still does not appear/screen is still black); besides, when I reboot the phone, "Disable HW overlays" is unchecked again - which is also an experience from a Samsung device later in the same thread:

> I have this exact same issue, and "Disable Hardware overlays" does not work on my Samsung Android phone.  Also everytime the phone is rebooted this feature is turned off, meaning hardware overlays are enabled.

So, my question is - is there anything I can do, to get VLC to properly play the video on the screen on this device?

Comment: Based on your description I would assume that the video contains frames that use features of the video codec your hardware decoder does not support. Therefore the video plays up to that frame. I don't know if it is possible or how to switch to software decoding. I would try other player such as MX player which can be easily switched to software decoding.

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback, @Robert - I forgot to say, the same videos play just fine in the default video player of Android, and also play fine in Asti Media Player installed on this device. So the problem is specifically with VLC - which I want to use primarily because it offers access to Linux NFS network shares (which, strangely, seem to be supported only by VLC and Kodi on Android, but typically not by Android file managers).

Comment: Then most likely it is a bug of VLC or one of it's used codec libraries. As you can't update to a newer version of VLC because of your ancient Android versions this way is blocked. May be you should try to install a custom ROM on your device. On [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/f/samsung-galaxy-xcover-2-roms-kernels-recoveries.5722/) there is a discussion on a 4.2 based ROM. As your phone is nearly 8 years old the options you have are limited.